# Attempting to create I/O txt file

Tags: c++

So I'm following my professors powerpoint and I think what I'm doing is correct, the issue I am having is when I execute my program I am unable to input anything.
Image at the bottom
"The input file should have some integer values (e.g., 10 values) separated by whitespaces."

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream myfile;
ofstream newfile;
myfile.open("test.txt");
newfile.open("new_test.txt");
cout <<"test.txt is opened to get input from it"<<endl;
cout <<"new_test.txt is opened to write in it"<<endl;

int mynum;
while(!myfile.eof())//finding whether end of file is reached
{
    myfile>>mynum;
    newfile<<mynum<<endl;
}
myfile.close();
newfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP88V.png)

My program isn't letting me input any letter/numbers or anything else for that matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You probably have your text file in the wrong location. Or perhaps it has 2 to .txt extensions because windows confused you by hiding the extension by default. Also please read the link from @Ron your code does contain the bug he mentions.

Comment: ***I don't have any errors in my program*** Not having any compiler errors does not mean you don't have logical errors.

Comment: BTW, neither of those statements are checked for their truth. You don't actually check if the open was successful in either case.

Comment: `myfile.open´ may fail. You are supposed to check for it. If you don't care whether an operation succeeds or fails, why bother with it at all?